# Best way to groupby when there are NaN's

Tags: python, pandas, merge, pandas-groupby

I have a previously merged panel dataset that looks like this:

```
ID | date 
01 | 01/01/2020
01 | 02/01/2020
01 | 03/01/2020
02 | NaN
03 | 15/02/2020
03 | 17/02/2020
```

As you can see, there are some IDs that don't have any related date. Date is in string format, not datetime.

I'm interested in getting a dataframe with **one row per ID**, where only the **last date is shown**.
It should look like this:

```
ID | date
01 | 03/01/2020
02 | NaN 
03 | 17/02/2020
```

I tried a few ways like:

`grouped = data1.groupby(["ID"]).last()` but that will not include the ID's that have `NaN` date.

Any ideas? I'm sure this is fairly simple but I don't have much experience with merge and groupby's

Comment: Use `drop_duplicates` with `last`

Comment: @jezrael Thank you! Just wondering, is it actually possible to achieve with groupby? In other answers with similar problems people use it but I haven't been able to make it work.

Comment: Then use `data1.groupby(["ID"]).tail(1)`

Comment: use df.groupby(by="ID", dropna=False, as_index=False) do additional aggrerate configuration to keep the last element